# why getting {Refference error} about {not defined} this script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm getting **ReferenceError: "dateclear4" is not defined. (line 9, file "Code")** script bellow.  I use dateclear4 as function how to define that?

basic function of script: Clear sheet data based on date values

```
function resetEmailValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sid = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AubCxU0AihqRdEdEM3FJM2MwLTFmakd4MktFeXZpLXc');
  var dd = ss.getSheetByName('SheetM').getRange('C1').getValues();
var trigger = dd.toString();

  if (trigger==4) { 
    dateclear4();
  }
  if (trigger==5) { 
    dateclear5();
  }



  function dateclear4() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sid = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AubCxU0AihqRdEdEM3FJM2MwLTFmakd4MktFeXZpLXc');
    var date4 = ss.getSheetByName('SheetM').getRange('C6').getValues();
  if (date4=="") {
    var values = sid.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('S2:Y73').setValue("");
    ss.getSheetByName('SheetM').getRange('C6').setValue("DONE");
}

  function dateclear5() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sid = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AubCxU0AihqRdEdEM3FJM2MwLTFmakd4MktFeXZpLXc');
    var date5 = ss.getSheetByName('SheetM').getRange('C7').getValues();
  if (date5=="") {
    var values = sid.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('S2:Y73').setValue("");
    ss.getSheetByName('SheetM').getRange('C7').setValue("DONE");
  }



  }
}
```

Comment: your calling the function before its defined

Comment: previous comment doesn't make sense... the order used to write your code is irrelevant. Simply correct the syntax errors you made and it will work as expected (missing braces)

Comment: @serge i can't get you.why it is irrelevant ?

Comment: Try writing your functions in any order, even in a different script file in the same project... it won't  change a single bit ... This is simply how it works : all the functions exist all together  during execution, no matter how they are written. btw, the code in your answer is still missing closing braces... please show correct code in answers.

Comment: for info : this is Google Apps Script.... rules are specific to the GAS environment and IDE. please read also the comment on your answer, the GAS IDE highlights the open/close braces and refuses to save a script when one of them is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calling  the below function "dateclear4 " before its defined.

```
function dateclear4() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sid = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AubCxU0AihqRdEdEM3FJM2MwLTFmakd4MktFeXZpLXc');
    var date4 = ss.getSheetByName('SheetM').getRange('C6').getValues();
  if (date4=="") {
    var values = sid.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('S2:Y73').setValue("");
    ss.getSheetByName('SheetM').getRange('C6').setValue("DONE");
}
}
```

call the function after its defined.

```
function resetEmailValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sid = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AubCxU0AihqRdEdEM3FJM2MwLTFmakd4MktFeXZpLXc');
  var dd = ss.getSheetByName('SheetM').getRange('C1').getValues();
var trigger = dd.toString();

  if (trigger==4) { 
    dateclear4();
  }
  if (trigger==5) { 
    dateclear5();
  }
}
```

or add the function in `window.dateclear4=function(){}`

Comment: Please reconsider your accept. Your code didn't work because a function definition must be enclosed in braces and since they were missing the function didn't exist. I'm surprised you didn't get a "syntax error" from the IDE in the first place. Normally you shouldn't even be able to save it as it is shown above.

Comment: yes you correct. function placement is not matter.but i dont know how the solution is worked for OP.

Comment: You're welcome :) (and I'm glad you didn't take it wrong, it was definitely not my intention !)